# How to get xetex to find a Truetype font?

Tags: fonts, xetex, lyx

I'm trying to compile a lyx document that uses the Crimson font.

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Crimson}

fontspec error: "font-not-found"

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| A font might not be found for many reasons.
| Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.
| 
| When in doubt, ask someone for help!
|...............................................
```

I'm on Mac OS X.  I have tried everything I can think of to install this font: the ttf file for the font is in the working directory, I've installed it with the OS's font book, I've placed the ttf in my ~/.fonts folder, my ~/texmf/fonts/truetype and my /usr/local/share/fonts.

What am I missing?

If it matters, the document I'm trying to compile is IlCensore's version of Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality from here: https://github.com/IlCensore/HPMOR-LyX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just put the font where all your system fonts are: `/Library/Fonts`.

Comment: For OS X, whenever you have a font problem, check **Font Book** to see if the font is (at least) available to the system. Then click *Show Font Info* to find out which name is the accessible one.

Comment: @AlanMunn That will create a second copy of the font since the OP has already installed it in the equivalent user-level folder. That isn't a great idea as it is liable to cause problems later, especially if one or other copy later gets updated. Also, unless things have changed, FontBook is not keen on duplicates. Better to check first that it *is* installed and what the info says as Symbol1 suggests.

Comment: In some cases in order for the font to be found  `Crimson.ttf` may have to used where the font is indicated. In this case `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Crimson.ttf}`

Comment: @Leucippus *If* the regular, upright font has that file name, yes. But, even then, this isn't the best way unless there's no other option. For what it is worth, that would fail miserably on my system as the relevant font is `Crimson-Roman.otf`. I don't know if the truetype is named similarly or not.

Comment: @cfr One Ubuntu machine I use the method presented in my former comment is the only way I can get a non-standard font to work. The other machines I use other methods can be utilized. One method to get started is better than no method at all.

Comment: @Leucippus Yes, but it should be a last resort and not to mention the disadvantages is misleading. This is ***not*** a `non-standard font`. At least, it certainly shouldn't be. As installed with my distro's package manager, it behaves in a perfectly standard way although you do, of course, need to tell `fontspec` the correct name for the font! Which is probably not `Crimson`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the truetype and opentype versions of the Crimson font are similar, the following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Crimson Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Crimson text]

It should work if you have the truetype but, since I've got the opentype version, that's the one I actually tested.

I'm not on a Mac so I can't use FontBook to get the name. The following method will work on any unix-based system (Mac OS X, GNU/Linux etc.) and should work on Windows if the path is adapted appropriately:

```
otfinfo -i <path to font file>/Crimson-Roman.otf 

Family:              Crimson
Subfamily:           Roman
Full name:           Crimson Roman
PostScript name:     Crimson-Roman
Version:             Version 0.8 
Unique ID:           FontForge : Crimson : 28-7-2010
Copyright:           Copyright (c) 2010, Sebastian Kosch (sebastian@aldusleaf.org),
with Reserved Font Name "Crimson".
This Font Software is licensed under the SIL Open Font License, Version 1.1.
This license is available with a FAQ at: http://scripts.sil.org/OFL
License URL:         http://scripts.sil.org/OFL
Vendor ID:           PfEd
```

`Full name` specifies the required name.

On my system, bold, italic and bold italic then work out-of-the-box as well.

[image: variations]